# How to route user after form validation in react functional component

Tags: reactjs, validation, routes, react-router

I rap button with link tag but when I click it, it directly jumping that page without validation, and i have used react-bootstrap form for validation.

```
    const SingIn = () => {
  return (
    <Form className="SingIn">
      <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicEmail">
        <Form.Label>Email address</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control type="email" placeholder="Enter email" required />
        <Form.Text className="text-muted">
          We'll never share your email with anyone else.
        </Form.Text>
      </Form.Group>

      <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicPassword">
        <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control type="password" placeholder="Password" required />
      </Form.Group>
      <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicCheckbox">
        <Form.Check type="checkbox" label="Check me out" />
      </Form.Group>

      <Link to="/movies">
        <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Link>

    </Form>
  );
};
```

Comment: Please provide us some code. What you want to validate and how are you routing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to change the route after validating.
there are 2 ways of doing this in react.
before we start keep in mind that you don't need a link tag in both cases:

```
<button onClick={handleClick}>click</button>
```

now you can try one of these ways in your handleClick function:

1- if you're using react-router-dom:

first import useHistory hook

```
const history = useHistory()
```

and in your handleClick function write:

```
  const handleClick = () => {
    //validate here
    history.push('/route')
  }
```

2- if you're not using react-router-dom:

```
  const handleClick = () => {
    //validate here
    window.location.href = '/route'
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You must, in my view, implement the `useNavigate` hook.
The `useHistory()` hook was replaced with the `useNavigate()` function in the React Router v6. Earlier, the `useHistory()` hook would access the React Router history object and use the push or replace methods to move between the other routers.

Install `npm install react-router-dom` after installing

`import { useNavigate } from react-router-dom`

1. `const navigate = useNavigate()`

After initializing useNavigate create click handler function.

2. `<button onClick={routeHandler}>click</button>`

The last step is where you enter your route information; after pressing the button, your page will be shown.

3. `const routeHandler = () => { navigate('pass your route') }`

for more information read the [ReactJS useNavigate() Hook](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reactjs-usenavigate-hook/)